# Is there a way to retroactively flatten merge commits?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-bisect

I have a git repo with a combination of commits and merges containing multiple commits. I am trying to use git bisect to determine where a bug was introduced, but when the resulting commit points to a merge commit with a dozen different commits, this is not as helpful.

Is there a way to retroactively flatten a merge commit into its individual commits? Or is there some other method of performing a git bisect that will allow you to continue into the individual commits of a merge commit?

Comment: Are we talking about _real_ merges? Or squashes?

Comment: Real merges I believe

Comment: What is a merge commit with different commits if this is not a squash ?

Comment: Can you use `git bisect --first-parent` and then do a second-level (second round?) bisect on the second parent of the offending merge commit?

Comment: Could the bug have been introduced via conflict resolution and not in one of the commits?

Comment: I think git bisect --first-parent would be the best approach. But I suppose this would still fail to catch issues due to resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The key factor here is to recognize that when using git-bisect to track down a bug you do not necessarily have to run along the original branch, you can also create a copy branch that you slightly modify.

The modifications I think of are things like for instance

- Temporary add some more files to `.gitignore` as the first commit in the bisect branch to make git status output clean.
- Fix commits that does not compile for trivial things like missing include statements etc.
- Disable unit test for parts of the system that are not affected by the bug you are trying to find (this can be a huge time saver).
- Split a large commit into multiple commits.
- Etc

Now of course any change might mask/fix errors/add new errors, but if you keep the changes small/unrelated to what you are suspecting this should normally be fine. In worst case this will not work, but most likely it can identify the problem in a commit on the copy branch which you then need to correlate with the same commit on the original branch.

---

Now for the case you describe I assume the you have something like the following

[image: gitk screenshot, start]

and you want to bisect between `main` and `Test-A`. To flatten merge commit you can use interactive rebase which by default flattens the history<sup>1</sup>. So with

```bash
git branch Test-A.bisect Test-A
git checkout Test-A.bisect
git rebase --interactive main       # Just saving and exiting the editor here.
git diff Test-A.bisect Test-A  # Verify that there are no unexpected differences.
```

then you end up with a `Test-A.bisect` branch without merges, which you then can run bisect on (with the caveat that it is not exactly the same as the original branch, but this very seldomly is a significant problem).

[image: gitk screenshot, end]

---

<sup>1</sup> You need to specify `--rebase-merges` for it to keep merge commits. I do include it by default in my `ri` alias for interactive rebase.